# Lambda expression in groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

We are using gradle 5.5

Below syntax:

```
def list = [1,2,3,4]
list.each(e -> println(e))
```

in `build.gradle` gives error:

```
  unexpected token: ->
```

---

Does groovy syntax allow lambda expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Gradle bundles Groovy 2.x. You can verify the exact version by doing the following in your `build.gradle`:

```
println "Groovy version: " + GroovySystem.getVersion()
```

You have to use a `Closure` instead:

```
def list = [1,2,3,4]
list.each({ e -> println(e) })
```

[Groovy 3](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#_java_style_lambda_syntax) does support the lambda syntax, but it's not known when Gradle will upgrade it's internal Groovy version.